# How to change reveal effect color in button in UWP?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

[image]

In my screenshot above, I would like to change the Gray highlight color in the above image to another color. Would anyone know how to do this? This is a Button control in UWP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify the style of the button.

Use Visual Studio templates for quick editing:

1. `Right click on the button control` in your xaml design window.
2. Select `Edit Template` ->`Edit a Copy..`. .
3. Select the location where the resource is stored. (it is recommended to use Resource Dictionary)
4. Edit the style that needs to be modified.

Modify the following parts. `ContentPresenter.BorderBrush`

```
<VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
<VisualState.Setters>
    <Setter Target="RootGrid.(RevealBrush.State)" Value="PointerOver"/>
    <Setter Target="RootGrid.Background" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonRevealBackgroundPointerOver}"/>
    <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.BorderBrush" Value="#FFFFFFFF"/>
...
<VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
<VisualState.Setters>
    <Setter Target="RootGrid.(RevealBrush.State)" Value="Pressed"/>
    <Setter Target="RootGrid.Background" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonRevealBackgroundPressed}"/>
    <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.BorderBrush" Value="#4D0087FF"/>
...
```

and refer to this style in your button.

```
 <Button Style="{StaticResource YourButtonStyle}".../>
```

Comment: It doesn't solve my problem. but at least I could understand what was going on. Thank you for your help.